# cut copy paste macro across 2 sheets with dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a range of A12:N112, Column A is my trigger column (1 or ) based on changing criteria).  The first bit of my macro which works sorts this range to all the rows with a 1 are at the top of the range.  It then opens the destination sheet as well.

The next bit of code below, needs to copy cells B:L for each row with a 1 in column A and paste that into the first empty row in the destination sheet starting at column D.  This then generates a number which the then copied and pasted back into the first sheet in column M of that specific row.  This then needs to loop until all of the rows with a 1 in column A have been processed.

Can anyone help, here is my code, which runs but nothing is copied or pasted.

```
Dim lr As Long lr = Sheets("Data Entry").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = lr To 2 Step 1
If Range("AB" & r).Value = "1" Then
Rows(r).Copy.Range ("A" & lr2 + 1)
Windows("Serialisation Log.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("SNo Log").Select
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Windows("Serialisation Log.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("SNo Log").Select
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Select
Selection.Copy

Windows("Serialisation Generator rev 1.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Data Entry").Select
Range("N").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End If
If Range("AB" & r).Value = "0" Then
   Range("I4").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Serial No. Issue complete for this OA"
End If
Range("F5").Select


Next r
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All these instances of `Select` and `Activate` are just adding overhead. If you properly qualify your ranges (and all objects) with a worksheet, you can avoid `Selecting` or `Activating` a sheet. VBA is indifferent to what cell, sheet, or book is selected

Comment: They also make code hard to read/follow, thus harder to debug. Cleaning these up will result in better readability and may make the issue stand out!

Comment: This line looks wrong:  Rows(r).Copy.Range ("A" & lr2 + 1) Should that be  Rows(r).Copy Range ("A" & lr2 + 1) . In fact, you should get a compile error in that case.

Comment: Put your workbooks into variables and refer to those. Fully qualify your range references with workbook and worksheet.

Comment: What happens if you change this part: `For r = lr To 2 Step 1` to this: `For r = 2 To lr`, does your code start the looping?